# 紙媒体で手元に届く大量の書面をDBに登録する

Tags: untagged

[紙媒体]⇒【複合機にてPDF化】⇒《データ化》⇒【DBインポート】

この一連の流れの中で
複合機で読み取りしたPDFファイルをExcelに変換して他のシステムに入力できるようデータ加工したいのですが、どうもうまく変換できるシステムがみつかりません。
今はPDFelementの試用版でテストをしていますが次のシステムに使えるレベルでデータは拾えていません。
ちなみに、複合機でスキャンするときの読み取り設定は、600dpiで読みとっています。

※端末情報
OS：Windows10 Pro / Windows8.1
office365

Comment: 「次のシステムに使えるレベルでデータは拾えていません。」は具体的にどんな問題が発生しているのでしょうか？それが分からないと回答のしようがないように思います。

Comment: <<データ化>> の部分を どのように考えているのかが ポイントとなりそうですね。 画像を OCR して日本語化 する場合は 読み取り効率を上げるためにいろいろ工夫が必要なので・・。 レイアウトを認識して この辺にこの情報がある。縦書きや 横書きが混在している。 というのを認識して OCR しないと、変な変換をしてしまいますよね・・。レイアウト解析や AI 解析して OCR する製品・ライブラリ  https://www.panasonic.com/jp/business/its/ocr_sdk/formocr.html  https://mediadrive.jp/products/library/chohyo_library/windows/index.html 等が あります。 これをさらにカスタマイズして システム化すると 銀行や 大手の事業所で行っているような OCR からデータ入力が自動で行えるシステムが構築できます。

Comment: 紙媒体のものがどのようなフォーマットであるかわかれば回答がつきやすいと思います。社外秘等もあると思いますが、サンプルをあげてもらうといいかもしれません。